# A wrong counter example (on distance and compactness)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Question: Let $E$ and $F$ be closed disjoint sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Show that if one of the sets is compact, then necessarily $d(E, F) > 0$.

A proof was provided, and I understand it, but I can't figure out why the following 'counterexample' does not work:

Let $E = \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}\ |\ n\in \mathbb{N} \right\} $ and $F = \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n \Big(\frac{1}{2^i} + \frac{1}{3^{i+1}}\Big)\ |\ n\in \mathbb{N}  \right\} $

Here, both $E$ and $F$ are compact, but $\nexists \epsilon > 0$ such that $d(E,F) > \epsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bot $E$ and $F$ are *not compact nor closed*, since they do not include their limit points
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}\;\text{ and }\;\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2^i}+\frac{1}{3^{i+1}}\right)
$$
therefore the theorem does not apply

**Note**
Following the comments, it should also be noted that *$E$ and $F$ are not compact since not any of their open covers contains a finite subcovering*: for example, think of the family of open balls 
$$
\mathcal{C}=\left\{\mathring{B}\big(x_i,10^{-i^2}\big)\right\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}_+}
$$
where

- $x_i=\frac{1}{2^I}$ or $x_i=\frac{1}{2^i}+\frac{1}{3^{i+1}}$, $i\in \mathbb{N}_+$ and
- $\mathring{B}(x_o,r)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|\,|x_o-x|<r\}$.

No one of its finite subfamilies covers the whole $E$ nor $F$.

Comment: But a compact subset of a metric space is closed and bounded.

Comment: I think @Daniele Tampeire meant to say $E$ and $F$ are no compact because they are not closed.

Comment: You're right @ThomasShelby: as Mr. Kavi Rama Murty pointed out, $E$ and $F$ are not compact because *they are not closed*: each finite (*sub*-)covering should be made of *open sets* in order to have compactness, an this is not the case.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: you're right. I have corrected the answer.